# Minecraft Titles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I put in this command:

```
/title @a title {"text":"YOUR NOSE IS A LITTLE BUTTON",color:"dark_green",bold:true}
```

I Got this error

```
[17:42:21] Invalid json: malformed JSON at line 1 column 41
```

Also, will the title only play when this command is activated?:

```
/title @a times 60 100 60
```

Answer (score 2):

All keys and strings in strict JSON must have quotation marks around them, except for `false` and `true`, which are considered booleans:

```
/title @a title {"text":"YOUR NOSE IS A LITTLE BUTTON","color":"dark_green","bold":true}
```

---

The `/title @a title` command is what plays the title, `/title @a times` will adjust the timing options for future titles, but not play the title itself.